# Sequence definition of Limit Sup

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Cannot understand the sequence definition of the  limit sup of a sequence ($a$n)
How can we say that $a$n < Lim sup + € except finitely many terms ( Why cant we say that $a$n< lim sup +€ for infinitely many terms?)
Also we are saying that $a$n> lim sup -€ for infinitely many terms.(why Cant we say that $a$n > lim sup -€ except finitely many terms ?) 
Does the two definition hold for every €> 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

'for infinitely many terms' is weaker than 'except finitely many terms'. For instance, a interger is odd for infinitely many intergers, but not except finitely many; a natural number is greater than 5 except finitely many numbers.